# Getting "$item is not defined" on applyBindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I'm trying to use knockout to do a pretty basic binding but am having trouble accessing the `$item` variable from jquery.tmpl.  I keep getting "`$item` is not defined" when I apply the bindings.

I've done this before so I know it can be done but I can't figure out why it is not working in this case.  What's interesting is if I remove `templateOptions:{parentItem: $item}`, then everything works as expected.

I've included the following files

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="Extension/resources/jquery.1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Extension/resources/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Extension/resources/knockout-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

My template and bindings look like this

```html
<script type="text/html" id="itemTemplate">
    <span data-bind="text:title"></span>
</script>

<div class="filterResults">
        <span  data-bind="text:message"></span>
        # of items: <span data-bind="text:contentItems().length"></span>
        <table cellspacing="0">
            <tr data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTemplate', foreach: contentItems, 
            templateOptions:{parentItem: $item} 
            }"> </tr>
        </table>            
</div>
```

And I do the binding using:

```
//viewModel contains a contentItems observableArray
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('.filterResults')[0]);
```

Comment: you get the error obviously because there is no such object defined as `$item`. What exactly are you trying to pass as `parentItem` ? You can access the current object using `${}` inside the template

Comment: right, I understand that the $item object is not defined.  What I can't figure out is why in this case it is not defined.  My understanding is it is an object that should be created and managed by jquery.tmpl.  There is an example in the knockout documentation on note 6 here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like I can answer this one myself.  The problem seems to be that the part where I did the data-bind and was trying to access the jquery.tmpl variable $item is not actually using jquery.tmpl

```
<tr data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTemplate', foreach: contentItems, 
        templateOptions:{parentItem: $item} 
        }"> </tr>
```

That is not inside a template so there is no $item variable to access.  $item is associated with jquery.tmpl, not knockoutjs.  The way I got around the issue was to just put my view model in there instead.

```
<tr data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTemplate', foreach: contentItems, 
        templateOptions:{parentItem: viewModel} 
        }"> </tr>
```

And in the actual templates, (itemTemplate in this example), I can access the $item variable.