# Binding checkboxes using KnockOutJS

Tags: knockout.js

In my application, there is a section of dynamically loaded 'locations'. The locations are objects, not simple strings (They have a name, id, and other properties). I need to be able to bind to the checked locations, and also want to track which ones are checked in a hidden input, such as storing a comma delimited string of locationId's.

I found a good example of this here:
[Working with a list of checkboxes in knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736136/working-with-checkboxes-in-knockoutjs/6737348#6737348)

Which led me to this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Jm2Mh/

However when I tried to re-write this using my location objects, it is throwing an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to parse bindings. 
Bindings value: attr: { value: $data }, checked: $item.selections 
Message: $item is not defined
```

Here is a JSFiddle of what I've done so far. (You can see the error above if press F12 and run it).
http://jsfiddle.net/toddhd/BkUUX/3/

While the error is obvious, $item is not defined, I do not really understand what $item is and why it works in the first example and not in mine.

Thanks for any help you can offer. Bonus points if anyone can help me re-write the code to display the selectedLocations also. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Item is not available because it is not supported in knockout's default templating mechanism. This is actually part of jQuery (see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663756/knockout-js-item-is-not-defined)). If you want to use it, you will have to override the default knockout templating mechanism.

That said, I have a fiddle here showing another way to do this without the need [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BkUUX/4/). Essentially, just add an isSelected property to each of your model objects and work off of that, it's certainly the simplest route.

```
var location = function (locationId, displayName, selected) {
    var self = this;
    self.LocationId = locationId;
    self.DisplayName = displayName;
    self.isSelected = ko.observable(selected);
```

};

In addition, the fiddle shows how to display the selected locations.

Answer (score 3):

[Here at Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ikbalouch/BkUUX/15/) you will find a working solution for your problem, also it will display the selected locations as well.

the html code is as:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'locationTmpl', foreach: locations, templateOptions: { selections: selectedLocations } }">/</div>
<script id="locationTmpl" type="text/html">

    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: $data.isSelected" />
    <span data-bind="text: $data.DisplayName"></span>
</script>
<hr />
<div data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(selectedLocations), null, 2)"></div>
<hr />
```

the javascript code is as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyLocation(locationId, displayName, selected) {
        this.LocationId = ko.observable(locationId);
        this.DisplayName = ko.observable(displayName);
        this.isSelected = ko.observable(selected);
    }

    var viewModel = function (items) {
        this.locations = ko.observableArray([
            new MyLocation('1', 'Starbucks1'),
            new MyLocation('2', 'Starbucks2', true),
            new MyLocation('3', 'Starbucks3'),
            new MyLocation('4', 'Starbucks4'),
            new MyLocation('5', 'Starbucks5')
        ]);

        //self.selectedLocations = ko.observableArray([self.locations()[1]]);                              
        this.selectedLocations = ko.computed(function () {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(
                this.locations(), function (item) {
                    return item.isSelected();
                }
                );
        }, this);
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
</script>
```

I have introduced a blog of same code as well, you can check it [by clicking this link](http://www.imranbalouch.com/blog/index.php/2013/07/knockout-js-managing-check-boxes/)

Comment: Thanks Imran. Your input was very helpful, and I appreciated the extra breakdown on selectedLocations. The other answer got the credit simply because it was first, both answers were almost identical, and SethCran's selectedLocation was a little more concise.

Comment: You are welcome Todd! I am glad that it was of some help to you. Regards